# View underneath other views and/or activities

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-activity

Is there a way to have one View opened all the time, and change the Activity on top of it? Or do I need to have that View called from all the Activities?
The idea is to have View on the bottom, and then move the upper one onClick to some position, so I reveal only a part of lower one. Lower one will have some buttons. Is there way to do that? And how? (some code, or pseudo-code would be nice. :) )

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Fragment. Think of a fragment like a partial activity. Fragments were introduced in Android 3.0 but using the Support Package, you can put Fragments in applications all the way back to Android 1.5.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

In your question, I'm assuming you're describing some kind of persistent footer. With Fragments, you'd write your application in a single Activity. A footer fragment would stay visible while body fragments would be swapped out by clicking on the footer. The Fragment hide/show example provided by Google should give you some good ideas.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentHideShowSupport.html